# Can an EXACT email address be validated in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

UPDATE: Thought this CLEARLY stated it was a homework assignment, and that the onus for reading what was written should lie with, well, those who are reading it, but someone advised that I should clarify that so the post doesn't get voted down by those who don't actually read it in its ENTIRETY!

So here goes: to clarify, I understand that client-side validation is insecure (and you should always use server-side validation for a real-world project) - again, this is just part of a college exercise to learn about the necessary syntax for something like this & should not be confused by anyone reading it as a real-world example...

---

I've been looking for sometime now, and trying many different things but nothing seems to work, so I'm not sure that this can even be done. Our homework assignment asks that we make it so only TWO (2) email/password combinations are able to login to our "website".

We're not using server-side validation, & the example we're given is simply to verify a minimum # of characters were entered into the email/password fields (HTML5 will be confirming that the correct email format is being used).

My question is this: can you write the JS to validate an EXACT email address/password only, i.e. Email: joe@joeschmoe.com / PW: blowhard. and, if anything else is input an error message would generate like the one generated by something like the first example, which is using the # of characters?? I'm not looking to use REGEX, just a single email address/password combo (actually, in this case it's 2 emails/2 passwords). Thanks, codes below are what I'm working on...

```
    // Validate!
if ((email.value.length > 0) && (password.value.length > 6)) {
    return true;
} else {
    alert('Please fill out the form accurately!');
    return false;
}
```

---

```
   // Validate!
if ((email.value == user@myonlinestore.com) && (password.value == JustMe69)) {
    return true;
} else {
    alert('Please fill out the form accurately!');
    return false;
}
```

.value is coming from the form elements reference below, and the HTML form itself that I'm using is listed after that:

```
    // Get references to the form elements:
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

---

```
    <form action="myaccount.html" method="get" id="loginForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required autofocus>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="submit"></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Login &rarr;" id="submit">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Authentication in client-side javascript? Why specifically TEACH bad ideas?

Comment: 1) where do you call your validation 2) where do you get the email object from. Normally you would want document.getElementById("email").value

Comment: Why would you want to? anyone could look at your script and determine what to enter - seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Guys, it's a school exercise that I have ZERO control over, sorry! I can't tell the teacher what to teach, I can only try to learn as it's being presented!

Comment: So you know, we'll be getting to server-side later on in the course, this is just to get us acclimated with some basic syntax since most in the class are very new to this...

Comment: Ahh, apologies. Missed the school exercise part. Blame my skim reading ;)

Comment: It might be good to add that you _understand_ that client-side validation is insecure (and that you should **always** use server side validation for a real-world project), but that you're just doing it to learn about the necessary syntax - some people might skim over and downvote this (though they shouldn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the email and password as strings by enclosing them in quotes:

```
if ((email.value == 'user@myonlinestore.com') && (password.value == 'JustMe69')) {
```

**edit**

After reading your update it appears that you don't need to use `email.value`. In this declaration:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

You have assigned the value of the `email` field to the `email` variable. Same goes for `password`, so you can check you email string ('user@myonlinestore.com') against the `email` variable:

```
if ((email == 'user@myonlinestore.com') && (password == 'JustMe69')) {
```

Comment: Thanks, Sebastien. Tried it but that doesn't work?!? The fact it can be done seems to be a YES, that's great! Now I have to determine why enclosing as a string won't work for me??

Comment: Please update your question and explain where `email.value` comes from.

Comment: Yes, that was it, Sebastien; thank you so much for your help with this, it's greatly appreciated! Hopefully I'll be able to better understand what I was doing wrong - doesn't look like I was that far off. BTW - unable to vote up your answer, still no reputation (besides a bad one, I guess?!?)...  :(